# "illegal start of type" while generating javadocs with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, spring-tool-suite

Friends, When I go to "Project > Generate Javadoc", I get the

```
illegal start of type
        List<FooOrder> rows = new ArrayList<>();
```

The error goes away when I set it as

```
List<FooOrder> rows = new ArrayList<FooOrder>();
```

What/how do I get around this issue? How can I ask eclipse ( or the ant task underneath it ) to ignore this issue?

I am using Jdk 1.7 / STS 3.6.4.RELEASE ( built on Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.2) )

Comment: In the wizard, did you go through all the page (using `next`) and select at the page 3 or 4 the `JRE source compatibility` to 1.7 or up ?

Comment: @flafoux, thanks for commenting. Yes, I set it to 1.7 ( default ). I also tried with 1.6 and 1.8 and get the same errors.

Comment: You tried it with 1.6 and 1.8 compatibility, or with a 1.6 and 1.8 JDK's JavaDoc tool?

Comment: @nitind, I tried with both 1.6 and 1.8 compatibility from the drop-downs. thank you.

Comment: Sounds to be like a bug in Eclipse and that the Javadoc generation doesn't support the diamond operator introduced in Java7. I would recommend to file a bug against Eclipse/JDT: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT